# How to get the Key of selected Entry of Firebase Database in Logcat?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[image]

> I am getting all the keys, How can I get the key of only the respective position of the cardview when I click on it? Suppose, if i click on card position 2, only that position key is required

Here is my Code :

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("News");
    final String z = databaseReference.child(String.valueOf(homeModelList.get(position))).getKey();

    Toast.makeText(context, z, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e("Position is ", String.valueOf(z));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I am unable to get the key of respective positions. I am getting Output in logcat as 0,1,2 which the positions of the adapter.

How can I get that Key. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the children of the `datasnapshot` to get the key using a for loop.

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Position is ", String.valueOf(childSnapshot.getKey()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting all the keys, How can I get the key of only the respective position of the cardview when I click on it? Suppose, if i click on card position 2, only that position key is required

Comment: @Zed You can create an `ArrayList` and add all the keys into it in the for loop; and then call `get()` method to get an item of a certain position .. wish that target your query